# Page redirects permanently to itself

Tags: config, redirect, loop, https

I am posting this in case anyone will encounter this problem. I also reported a potential bug about that. (see here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues)

When you start to suddenly get redirection loops with HTTP-302 redirects to our own page, you might want to check your loginPath value in general.php.

After we spent hours investigating into the usual .htaccess and other places for redirection loops, we eventually figured out, that loginPath set to '/' will cause that behaviour.

We wanted to redirect users to the homepage if they were not logged in and tried to access a page that required a login.

Our setting was:

```
'loginPath' => '/'
```

which proved to cause the redirection loop.

The correct setting instead was:

```
'loginPath' => ''
```

I hope this saves somebody else from future pain :)

Comment: It's clear that this is a bug report, and not a question to be answered. Please report all bugs directly to support@craftcms.com

Answer (score 0):

Answer is provided in the original post and this can be assumed solved.